# Is there a way to clear the last thing I clicked?

Tags: javascript

I had a perfectly working calculator that only worked with mouse clicks, but I wanted more so I added a keyboard event. Now when I click something (digit or operation to perform) it somehow keeps remembering the last thing I clicked after pressing enter on the keyboard for the answer. Gor example if I click `2*3` and press enter on keyboard it will remember the `3` so answer will show `63` and if I click `2*` and press `3` and enter on the keyboard it will remember the `*` and think I want to multiply again.

here is my application on jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/qohuxoz/edit?html,css,js,output

I only added the keyboardInput const and the window.onload and the keyboard event.
I just want to know how to fix this bug.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. I'd bet you can whittle this down to just a demo of the problem rather than dumping your entire app on the table. :) Also, please find your shift and question mark keys and properly punctuate your English for easier reading. "I" is always capitalized.

Comment: You can create snippet with your html and CSS along with this javascript code.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the previous focused element. when I press enter the program executes the event for the previous focussed button AND the key I recently pressed! anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY i got it after so much trial and error
I just had 2 blur the button when clicking it like this:

```
numberButtons.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
        button.blur()
    })
})
```

i did it for all other type of buttons
hopes this helpes someone